# why should I use .Send({from:this.state.account}) in web3 interface to receive ether from the contract?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

I have sent/deposited Ether to my smart contract using ReactJS as front-end and web3 as interface using the below code.

```
await this.state.Bank.methods.desposit().send({value:amountInEther.toString(),from:this.state.account})
```

and while trying to receive ether from the smart contract using frontend Reactjs i have used this code

```
(React code) await this.state.Bid.methods.withDraw(this.state.account).call()
dbank.sol(solidity below code):

function withDraw(address payable receiver)public{
        receiver.transfer(accounts[receiver]);
        accounts[receiver]=0;
     }
```

when i tried this it didn't work but when I changed the react code from call to send with address it worked

```
await this.state.Bid.methods.withDraw().send({from:this.state.account})
```

But WHY? and also when i use this metamask is taking some gas fees to run this. Don't you think smart contract has to give the ether to us and it should pay the Gas fee.
We are paying Gas fee while sending the ether to the contarct Is okay acceptable but why should we pay the gas fee to receive our ether from the contract?

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, because the web3 library was made that way,just that simple, there are other libraries that have different ways of handle that, but what does `{from: this.state.account}` is pass the information necessary to the library to sign the transaction and send it

About your second question, to the ethereum network currently (and probably never) does not exist a way to distinguish a "withdraw" from a transaction, because there are exactly the same, remember that you are calling a contract function that will modify the state of the blockchain, that call will become a transaction and the transaction has to pass the hole process, minting, verification and all of that, so as any transaction you have to pay gas